# How to execute Create Trigger SQL statement within C# code

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want that a specific trigger gets created dynamically whenever it is deleted using C# code.

The part that checks existence of the trigger is done, but I don't know how to execute the `create trigger` in c# code. I am not sure if the `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteQuery` would work or none of them at all.

Comment: Side point: you can just do `CREATE OR ALTER` which will either create or replace the trigger, no need to check existence

Comment: You mean it will replace the old trigger even though they have the same name?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments *"`OR ALTER` Conditionally alters the trigger only if it already exists."*

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET `SqlCommand` class has several methods to execute SQL code.

- `ExecuteReader`: returns an IDataReader to read data
- `ExecuteScalar`: returns a single, atomic value from a SQL statement
- `ExecuteNonQuery`: does not return any data, but executes the SQL statement passed

Just from the short description, it should be very clear which one you need to use - `ExecuteNonQuery` - since the two other methods both return data to the caller - this is *not* the case when you're creating a trigger in SQL code.

So just set up a normal `SqlConnection` to the database you want to create the trigger in, create a `SqlCommand` and define the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement as its command text, and then run `ExecuteNonQuery` on that `SqlCommand` - done.

Comment: I got it . Thanks for the elaboration.... I wonder if there is a way to make that trigger drop/delete proof especially when Application is not executed?